# Jquery look up dynamically created Id and wireup function

Tags: jquery, .net

I have a jquery function to expand and collapse a div by id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#mySlideContent').css('display','none');
    $('#mySlideToggler').click(function(){
        $('#mySlideContent').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I would like to have multiple slideContent divs each wired up the respective slideToggler div. However number of slideContent and slideToggler divs are created dynamically on the page with a 'for each' as seen below.

```
<% For Each c In Contacts%>
    <li id="grid_<%= c.ContactId %>" class="grid">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="mySlideToggler">
                    <label>Name</label> 
                </div>
                <div id="mySlideContent" class="col-inner">
                    <%= c.Name%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<%Next%>
```

How can I pass in my dynamically created id of my div's so that I can reuse my function.

Comment: Why don't you use classes instead? `.slideToggler` and `.slideContent` should suffice.

Comment: Yes, i had it setup like this originally, however every toggle div opened and closed every content div. I was looking for functionality that had 1 toggle for each content div dynamically created.

Comment: That's just a question of how to traverse the DOM correctly, have a look at the answer below for a perfect example of how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .net code would create invalid html, as it would create multiple elements with the same `mySlideToggler` and `mySlideContent` ids.. (*and the id must be unique*)

If you would change it to create valid html (*using classes instead*)

```
<% For Each c In Contacts%>
    <li id="grid_<%= c.ContactId %>" class="grid">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="mySlideToggler">
                    <label>Name</label> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-inner mySlideContent">
                    <%= c.Name%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<%Next%>
```

Then use the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.mySlideContent').hide();
    $('.mySlideToggler').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, i had it setup like this originally, however every toggle div opened and closed every content div. I was looking for functionality that had 1 toggle for each content div dynamically created.

Comment: @Princess, you must have used `$('.mySlideContent').slideToggle('fast')`. If you read more carefully the code you will see `$(this).next().slideToggle('fast')`. the `$(this).next()` part finds the next element from the clicked one and not all similar elements..

Comment: aight, let me give it a shot.